# Connecting To Multiple Wallets Simultaneously To Dapp On The Frontend

Tags: blockchain, wallets, nft, dapp-development, frontend

I'm exploring the possibility of building a Dapp that enables the user to connect multiple wallets simultaneously.  The reason is that for my particular use case, the NFT category that I'm observing span across multiple blockchain networks (Ethereum, Polygon, Algorand, etc.) and not all NFT projects support the same wallets.  The application is only going to support read functionality from the blockchain(s), so no transaction capabilities.

There are frameworks like WalletConnect that support multiple wallets, but not the ability to connect to them at the same.  Seems that Web3.js and Web3.py might be the only ones that could even support such a feature.  Is this the case?  Or is there another framework that would allow for what I'm looking for?

Or maybe there's another approach that I haven't considered.

Comment: Do you really need a wallet? If you will only connect to read data without creating transaction, you could connect to several api providers to query data with only an address.

Answer (score 0):

To get this up and running quickly, just go with a Web3 API to fetch NFTs.
You need to check if all the chains you want are provided, by the provider you choose. Here are just some examples, there are many of them.

Check Moralis NFT API:
https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/nft-api

Check Alchemy NFT API:
https://www.alchemy.com/nft-api

Check Ankr NFT API:
https://www.ankr.com/docs/advanced-api/nft-methods/#ankr_getnftsbyowner